# Visual Studio - Find in File - Display matching strings

Tags: visual-studio, findinfiles

Using Visual Studio 2012.

Trying to use Find in Files to find all strings in code matching a certain string.
E.g. searching for "usp_", matches would include "usp_blah", "usp_test".

Rather than displaying **files** wherein the matching strings occur in the **Find Window 1**, I want to see a **list of the matching strings**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The results will show both the file and the line of code that matched
if there are multiple matches in one file there will be a line for each

filname1 ----- line 20 of code with the match line of code 
filname2 ----- line 50 of code with the match line of code

i know you said you don't want a list of the files in the find window and i may be pointing out something you already know but figured i would just point that out incase you didn't see it.

i generally pull the find result out and full screen it when i am trying to review the results